# get data from querystring in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im very new to getting data from one page to another and i have used querystring to pass data. and looks like this:

```
?redesigndata={"jsondata": "{\"images\":[ {\"src\":\"images/bgset.jpg\"},{\"src\":\"images/ar019.png\"}]}","product_hardware": "silver","product_thread": "white","product_lining": "Blue","product_lining_loc": "images/lining/blue_80x32.jpg"}
```

How do i remove all the `\` from it and then put it into an object or any thing like this with Javascript or jQuery:

```
redesigndata = {
    "jsondata": "{"images":[ {"src":"images/bgset.jpg"},{"src":"images/ar019.png"}]}",
    "product_hardware": "silver",
    "product_thread": "white",
    "product_lining": "Blue",
    "product_lining_loc": "images/lining/blue_80x32.jpg"
}
```

Comment: [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location.search` will get you the querystring (starting with the `?`).  Strip off the `?`, split it at `=`, then `JSON.parse` it.

```
var jsonStr = location.search.substring(1).split('=');
var obj = JSON.parse(unescape(jsonStr[1]));
```

Then you can parse `jsondata`.

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse(obj.jsondata);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you remove those backslashes? Without them you the JSON wouldn't be valid anymore. Right now you have nested JSON so you can parse it like this (with `str` being the `redesigndata` value):

```
var redesigndata = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(str).jsondata);
```

Comment: i didnt know the back slashes were important. Thanks